# How can I delete a file or directory in API Level >= 23?

Tags: java, android, file

I have an android app that delete a specific files or directories .this app work on android with API less than 23 but doesn't work on API 23 and above .
i wrote manifest permissions and wrote run time permission for read and write data on external sdcard .but didn't work .i wrote run time permissions with dexter library but again didn't work.
at last i delete part of code that delete files and directories on external sdcard and only want to delete directories on internal sd card but again have same result (again API>23 not work )

```
public double deleteFileOrDirectory(String fileOrDirectory) {
    File FOD = new File(fileOrDirectory);
    if (FOD.exists() && FOD.isFile() && FOD.canWrite()) {
        FOD.delete();
    } else if (FOD.exists() && FOD.isDirectory() && FOD.canRead()) {
        String fileList[] = FOD.list();
        if (fileList != null && fileList.length == 0) {
            FOD.delete();
            // return 0;
        } else if (fileList != null && fileList.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                File temp_f = new File(FOD.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileList[i]);
                if (temp_f.isDirectory())
                    deleteFileOrDirectory(temp_f.getAbsolutePath());
                else if (temp_f.isFile())
                    temp_f.delete();
            }

        }
        if (FOD.exists())
            if (FOD.delete()) {
                //return 0;
            }
    }
    // return -1;
    double[] v = volumCalcultor();
    return v[2];

}
```

i want to delete file for all android device -At least I want to delete the directories from the internal memory with any specific permission.

Answer (score 1):

API23+ considers the External SD card to be a 'semi-permanent' device and as such will not grant write access anything outside of the App private directory

Comment: So is there another way for deleting files on sdcard?